# iOS - entire View shifts up after rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video

Doing a very simple iPad app that plays a video in fullscreen. I want the video perfectly centered, but on initial load it's a bit too far down. When I rotate it, the view resets itself properly to be perfectly centered. Obviously I'd love to have it look this way from the start.

Here's my code in viewDidLoad:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"m4v"]];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenBounds.size.height, screenBounds.size.width)];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
[moviePlayer play];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

The app is set to only show in landscape mode, so the rotation takes effect every 180 degrees (instead of 90). BTW the moviePlayer var is set in the .h file like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

Then it's synthesized in my ViewController:

```
@synthesize moviePlayer;
```

So does anyone have any ideas? I tried changing "setFrame" to start at 0,-20 instead of 0,0 but that messed things up on the later rotations. If there's a way to ignore the dumb status bar on initial load, I'd love to know it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

in the viewcontroller implementation. This should force it to "ignore the dumb status bar on initial load".

Comment: This seems more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: 1) It is an answer. 2) I see no way to comment on other posts. Are specific privileges needed?

Comment: 1) Its not an answer cause you are asking the user a question not answering his question. 2) under every answer and question there is the option to "add comment" no privileges needed everyone can do it. If this is an answer make it so your not asking a question yourself, and explain your answer for example - "Why do it this way?"

Comment: I have edited my response. I only see the Add Comment link below my own answers, not any others. Using iPad.

Comment: +1 for correcting. I would say there is an issue with the iPad version of the site than, as commenting is not restricted.

Comment: Thanks to both who answered -- the other answer might work too, but this one was shorter and immediately solved my problem. Thanks!!

Comment: Popeyes, turns out commenting is restricted, it requires a Reputation of 50: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Comment: My full apologies then. It seems pointless that it is at 50, because if you want to help but don't have an actually answer then you will get downvotes for not providing as comment. So I apology's again.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the frame in `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Layout should be handled there, not in the setup methods.